# Convert only digits to int in a std::string

Tags: c++, string, int, std

I'm trying to convert only the digits from a string to an int vector, but that gives me the ASCII codes for numbers 0 to 9 instead.

Is there any way to convert only the digits to integers? I guess I'll have to use a char array since atoi() don't work with std::string and the c_str() method don't work for every character, only the entire string.

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string chars_and_numbers = "123a456b789c0";
    vector<int> only_numbers;

    for (int i = 0; i < chars_and_numbers.length(); i++) {
        if (isdigit(chars_and_numbers[i])) {
            cout << chars_and_numbers[i] << " ";
            only_numbers.push_back(int(chars_and_numbers[i]));
        }
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (vector<int>::iterator i = only_numbers.begin(); i != only_numbers.end(); i++) {
        cout << *i << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 48
```

Comment: Would `istringstream` do what you need? Better yet, please give an example input and expected output.

Comment: `int(chars_and_numers[i])` doesn't do what you think it should. The `char` type is an integral type, like `int` or `short`. It holds the (usually) ASCII integer value of the character, which is why `'0'` is showing up in your array as `48`. To convert a digit to it's integer equivalent, use `chars_and_numbers[i] - '0'`, which subtracts the integral value of `'0'` from the digit's ASCII value, yielding `0` for `'0'`, `1` for `'1'`, and so on. Of course, you'll probably want to use a `stringstream` for this particular case, so that isn't very helpful, but it should at least teach you something.

Comment: Again I wish for the non-existent `transform_if` algorithm.

Comment: Anyway, do you want `only_numbers` to look like `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 }` or `{ 123, 456, 789, 0 }` when you're done?

Comment: Like the first one. stringstream would give me the numbers between characteres instead individual digits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ASCII Character    ASCII Code(decimal)  Literal Integer
      '0'               48                      0
      ...               ...                    ...
      '9'               57                      9
```

`int(chars_and_numbers[i])` returns you the underlying ***ASCII code*** of ASCII character instead of the literal integer what you want.

Generally, `'i' - '0'` results in `i` if `i` belongs to [0, 9].

*E.g.*, `'1' - '0'` returns you the *distances* between values of two ASCII characters(49 - 48), which is *1*.

```
int main() {
    string chars_and_numbers = "123a456b789c0";
    vector<int> only_numbers;

    for (int i = 0; i < chars_and_numbers.length(); i++) {
        if (isdigit(chars_and_numbers[i])) {
            cout << chars_and_numbers[i] << " ";
            // here is what you want
            only_numbers.push_back(chars_and_numbers[i] - '0');
        }
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (vector<int>::iterator i = only_numbers.begin(); i != only_numbers.end(); i++) {
        cout << *i << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think what the OP _actually_ wants to do is have `only_numbers` hold `{ 123, 456, 789, 0 }`. But I could be wrong. It's ambiguous.

Comment: Yup, it's not that clear. I assume the "digits" he mentioned is individual digits.

Comment: Yes, Eric and George Gaál, I just want the individual digits. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @Tiago, if Eric's answer solves your problem, you should vote it as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

If your desired output when printing the vector of ints are the actual numbers 0 through 9, you can rely on the fact that the ASCII values for '0' through '9' are consecutive:

```
only_numbers.push_back(char_and_numbers[i] - '0');
```

Thus, '8' becomes '8' - '0', or 56 - 48, which is 8.

Comment: You don't need to rely on ASCII, you can rely on the fact that the standard mandates that digit characters be stored consecutively in the character set. (It does not do the same for alphabet characters, and indeed EBCDIC does not do so, but for digits you're safe.)

Comment: @George Gaál - You won't be using `std::string` for Unicode (I hope).

Comment: There are many misconceptions. As I understand there are different types of Unicode. One of them is UTF-8, which perfectly fit in std::string. But I can't say that this is best way to contain it.

Comment: George: Unfortunately, there are also many misconceptions surrounding the misconceptions. There is only one Unicode. (But there are many ways to represent a sequence of Unicode codepoints.)

Comment: @Kerrek SB, you are right. But codepoints refer to some numbers, which we can analyze. And substract too :)